# get scrolled position of ScrollView in dp

Tags: android, scrollview, floating-action-button

I want to show fab if user has scrolled below certain height, but i need dp value from getSrollY. How can i do it?

```
scroll = ScrollView.getScrollY();
    if(scroll<500){
                fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                fab1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
                fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fab1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

getScrollY is giving output in pixels, how can i get it in dp?

Comment: Studio shows no error, but fab is not getting invisible. i just put in arbitrary value 500 to see what happens, i read that getscrollY gives output in pixel value, but i need it in dp value

Comment: I think your else statement is executed irrespective of `scroll` value remove `else` try  `if(scroll<500){ .. } if(scroll>=500){ .. }`